# What's the best way to transform Array values in one column to columns of the original DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logistic-regression

I have a table where one of the columns is an Array of binary features, they are there when that feature is present.

I'd like to train a logistic model on these rows, but can't get the data in the required format where each feature value is it's own column with a 1 or 0 value.

Example:

```
id    feature values
1     ['HasPaws', 'DoesBark', 'CanFetch']
2     ['HasPaws', 'CanClimb', 'DoesMeow']
```

I'd like to get it to the format of

```
id    HasPaws    DoesBark    CanFetch    CanClimb    DoesMeow
1     1          1           1           0           0
2     1          0           0           1           0
```

It seems like there would be some functionality built in to accomplish this, but I can't think of what this transformation is called to do a better search on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first convert lists to columns and then use [get_dummies()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) method:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   id                 feature_values
0   1  [HasPaws, DoesBark, CanFetch]
1   2  [HasPaws, CanClimb, DoesMeow]

In [13]: (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('id').feature_values.apply(pd.Series),
    ...:                 prefix='', prefix_sep='')
    ...:    .reset_index()
    ...: )
Out[13]:
   id  HasPaws  CanClimb  DoesBark  CanFetch  DoesMeow
0   1        1         0         1         1         0
1   2        1         1         0         0         1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to loop through the `feature values` column, and construct a series from each cell with the values in the list as index. And in this way, pandas will expand the series into a data frame with `index` as headers:

```
pd.concat([df['id'], 
          (df['feature values'].apply(lambda lst: pd.Series([1]*len(lst), index=lst))
          .fillna(0)], axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

***method 1***

```
pd.concat([df['id'], df['feature values'].apply(pd.value_counts)], axis=1).fillna(0)
```

***method 2***

```
df.set_index('id').squeeze().apply(pd.value_counts).reset_index().fillna(0)
```

***method 3***

```
pd.concat([pd.Series(1, f, name=i) for _, (i, f) in df.iterrows()],
          axis=1).T.fillna(0).rename_axis('id').reset_index()
```

[image]